# Push 1st array in object to itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to repeat the first array in an array of arrays using:

```
  var scribble = [1,2,3,4]
  scribble = [scribble]

  for (var i = 0; i<3; i++){
    scribble.push(scribble[0]);
  }
```

The desired result would be:
`[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]`

But it just pushes in `[]` each time. Am I missing something?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Provide [mcve]. Your code works fine in GAS.

Comment: I think I've got it. I was stepping through the code in the console and that was where I was seeing the result but logging it at the end  gives the correct value. Is that a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You code should work. Alternatively you can make a copy of the first element from the original array and push it

```js
var scribble = [1, 2, 3, 4];
scribble = [scribble];


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  scribble.push([...scribble[0]]);
}

console.log(scribble)
```